# How to do I sum these postgresql two tables and group by week and year?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to sum two tables sales + waste with results grouped by week and year. If I run each section by itself I get accurate results, but when I try my current query I get an error of "[42601] ERROR: subquery must return only one column"

This is what I currently have...

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT date_part('week', w."createdAt"),
        SUM("Quantity")
    FROM waste as w
     WHERE date_trunc('year', w."createdAt"::timestamptz at time zone 'America/Denver') =
           date_trunc('year', current_date - interval '1 year')
    group by 1
)
    +
(
    SELECT date_part('week', sh.”createdAt"),
           SUM(quantity)
    FROM sales_hourly as sh
    WHERE date_trunc('year', sh."createdAt"::timestamptz at time zone 'America/Denver') =
          date_trunc('year', current_date - interval '1 year')
    group by 1
) AS weekly_total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join both tables, but as both tables could have different weeks, you need a FULL OUTER JOIN which will cost time.

If it is guaranteed that both SELECTs have the same weeks , a INNER JOIN will suffice.

> ```
> CREATE tABLE waste("createdAt" timestamp  , "Quantity" integer )
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE sales_hourly("createdAt" timestamp  , "Quantity" integer)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.week_t1,COALESCE(sum_t1,0) sum_waste,t2.week_t2,  COALESCE(sum_t2,0) sum_slaes
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT date_part('week', w."createdAt") week_t1,
>         SUM("Quantity") sum_t1
>     FROM waste as w
>      WHERE date_trunc('year', w."createdAt"::timestamptz at time zone 'America/Denver') =
>            date_trunc('year', current_date - interval '1 year')
>     group by 1
> ) t1
>     FULL OUTER JOIN 
> (
>     SELECT date_part('week', sh."createdAt") week_t2,
>         SUM("Quantity") sum_t2
>     FROM sales_hourly as sh
>      WHERE date_trunc('year', sh."createdAt"::timestamptz at time zone 'America/Denver') =
>            date_trunc('year', current_date - interval '1 year')
>     group by 1) t2 ON t1.week_t1 = t2.week_t2
> ```

> ```
> week_t1 | sum_waste | week_t2 | sum_slaes
> :------ | --------: | :------ | --------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c35e958af4ac1b69ddbc9a7431c23ac2)*

Comment: Thank you this was a huge help. Is it possible to get results that show week and sum of waste + sales? I have tried adding to your query and am still having difficulties.

Comment: add another column with `COALESCE(sum_t1,0) +COALESCE(sum_t2,0)`